# GPS starts emitting data as soon as I kill GPSD

Tags: gpsd

I can't really figure out how GPSD works. If I start gpsmon nothing happens. But if I run sudo killall gpsd immediately position starts to appear on screen.

The same happens in my node app. I start receiving position as soon as I kill gpsd (after starting my program).

I'm using Garmin USB GPS 18x and a Jetson TX2 on Node v8.11.3. In my program I'm using node-gpsd to handle the GPS data.

Answer (score 1):

The `gpsd` deamon reads out the GPS-data coming via the serial interface and provides them to other applications via a socket on a specific port (default: port 2947).

The client program `gpsmon` can be run in one of two modes.

- as a client for `gpsd` using the socket provided by `gpsd`
- in direct mode, reading out the data coming from the serial interface of the GPS device

Which of both modes you use is determined, with which arguments you start `gpsmon`.
I don't know, how you start `gpsmon`, but judging by your description, I assume you start `gpsmon` in direct mode and therefore only see data, once you kill `gpsd` and have `gpsmon` access the serial interface, which was before used by `gpsd`.

In order to use `gpsmon` as client for `gpsd`, please refer to the [official documentation](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/gpsmon.html) of `gpsmon`.

Regarding your node app:
It's just a guess, but I assume this app is not using the socket provided by `gpsd`, but wants to listen on the serial interface directly. Thus the behaviour you observe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've reproduced the following scenario: If I start Jetson and run `gpsmon localhost:2947` i see the gps data. If I stop `gpsmon` and run `gpsmon localhost:2947` i see a blank screen and if I press enter i see `tcp://localhost:2947 Unknown device>`. If I leave this screen and kill or restart gpsd, gpsmon automatically starts working again. I can't figure out how to reconnect to gpsd without killing or restarting it. I assume `gpsmon localhost:2947` means running gpsmon as client for gpsd, right?

Comment: Yes, `gpsmon localhost:2947` will run it as client for gpsd. In the setups, where I have been using `gpsd` I never had an issue as you described. How do you stop `gpsmon`?

Comment: ctrl + C. is this a wrong way?

Comment: no that's fine. In order to see, if the problem is on `gpsmon` side or `gpsd` side you could do the following test. After stopping `gpsmon` does `gpsd` still work with other applications such as `cgps` or `xgps`?

Comment: No other application related to GPSD works until I kill GPSD. I recorded a short video showing this:

https://youtu.be/puA0Vq9ARrM

Comment: Seems that stopping `gpsmon` also messes up `gpsd`. Maybe `journalctl -u gpsd.service -u gpsd.socket` gives you some interesting information about the status of `gpsd`.